# Is there easy way to extract connection string from legacy java MongoClient

Tags: java, mongodb

Is there easy way (or a library) that would extract mongo connection string from legacy `com.mongodb.MongoClient` object?

I know that I could extract all that information from `MongoClient` and build the connection URI myself, but it seems to be error prone.

If there's way to create `com.mongodb.client.MongoClient` instance from `com.mongodb.MongoClient` then it would good solution for my problem as well.

Comment: What MongoClient version are you using ?

Comment: 3.9.1, but the same applies to the newst 3.12.6

Comment: This is generally not a supported operation because not all client options have corresponding URI options.

Comment: That's useful information, thanks. So there's another question - is there easy way to create new `com.mongodb.client.MongoClient` from legacy `com.mongodb.MongoClient `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [D.SM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9540925/d-sm) has mentioned in the comment, it's better to create new MongoClient from legacy client instead of creating it from connection string, because not all client options have corresponding URI options.
So far I came with:

```
    private com.mongodb.client.MongoClient fromLegacyClient(MongoClient legacyMongoClient) {
        MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions = legacyMongoClient.getMongoClientOptions();
        MongoClientSettings.Builder mongoClientSettingsBuilder = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .readPreference(legacyMongoClient.getReadPreference())
                .writeConcern(legacyMongoClient.getWriteConcern())
                .retryWrites(mongoClientOptions.getRetryWrites())
                .readConcern(legacyMongoClient.getReadConcern())
                .codecRegistry(mongoClientOptions.getCodecRegistry())
                .compressorList(mongoClientOptions.getCompressorList())
                .applicationName(mongoClientOptions.getApplicationName())
                .commandListenerList(mongoClientOptions.getCommandListeners())
                .codecRegistry(mongoClientOptions.getCodecRegistry())
                .applyToClusterSettings(clusterSettings -> {
                    clusterSettings.hosts(legacyMongoClient.getAllAddress());
                    clusterSettings.localThreshold(mongoClientOptions.getLocalThreshold(), MILLISECONDS);
                    clusterSettings.serverSelectionTimeout(mongoClientOptions.getServerSelectionTimeout(), MILLISECONDS);
                    clusterSettings.serverSelector(mongoClientOptions.getServerSelector());
                    clusterSettings.requiredReplicaSetName(mongoClientOptions.getRequiredReplicaSetName());
                    mongoClientOptions.getClusterListeners().forEach(clusterSettings::addClusterListener);
                })
                .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(connectionPoolSettings -> {
                    mongoClientOptions.getConnectionPoolListeners().forEach(connectionPoolSettings::addConnectionPoolListener);
                    connectionPoolSettings.maxConnectionIdleTime(mongoClientOptions.getMaxConnectionIdleTime(), MILLISECONDS);
                    connectionPoolSettings.maxConnectionLifeTime(mongoClientOptions.getMaxConnectionLifeTime(), MILLISECONDS);
                    connectionPoolSettings.maxWaitTime(mongoClientOptions.getMaxWaitTime(), MILLISECONDS);
                })
                .applyToSocketSettings(socketSettings -> {
                    socketSettings.connectTimeout(mongoClientOptions.getConnectTimeout(), MILLISECONDS);
                    socketSettings.readTimeout(mongoClientOptions.getSocketTimeout(), MILLISECONDS);
                })
                .applyToServerSettings(serverSettings -> {
                    mongoClientOptions.getServerListeners().forEach(serverSettings::addServerListener);
                    serverSettings.minHeartbeatFrequency(mongoClientOptions.getMinHeartbeatFrequency(), MILLISECONDS);
                    serverSettings.heartbeatFrequency(mongoClientOptions.getHeartbeatFrequency(), MILLISECONDS);

                })
                .applyToSslSettings(sslSettings -> {
                    sslSettings.enabled(mongoClientOptions.isSslEnabled());
                    sslSettings.invalidHostNameAllowed(mongoClientOptions.isSslInvalidHostNameAllowed());
                    sslSettings.context(mongoClientOptions.getSslContext());
                });
        if (legacyMongoClient.getCredential() != null) {
            mongoClientSettingsBuilder.credential(legacyMongoClient.getCredential());
        }
        return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettingsBuilder.build());
    }
```